# Razor как вставить двоеточие (:)

Tags: c#, razor

Как вывести двоеточие в данном примере между выводом `Label` и `task.Count`:

```
@foreach (var task in Model.TaskComplitedByUser)
{
    @Html.Label(task.Label) @task.Count
}
```

Чтобы в результате получить к примеру:

```
<label for="">Текст</label>: 0
```

Так пробовал не работает:

```
@Html.Label(task.Label) @: @task.Count
@Html.Label(task.Label) @:: @task.Count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вариант 1:

```
@Html.Label(task.Label)<text>:</text> @task.Count
```

вариант 2:

```
@Html.Label(task.Label) @Html.Encode(":") @task.Count
```

вариант 3:

```
@Html.Label(task.Label) Write(":"); @task.Count
```

вариант 4:

```
@Html.Label(task.Label) @":" @task.Count
```

Comment: Работает. Это единственный вариант для двоеточия?

Comment: возможно будет работать еще так: `@Html.Encode(":")`

Comment: Надо отметить, что все эти варианты требуются только в режиме C#-кода. В режиме HTML работает простое двоеточие.